# React AntD Forms Error Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components)

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, antd

I am running into this error when trying to utilize AntD forms:

`Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components)`

I have done research and a lot of topics discuss how the component is being imported/exported

However, I am unsure if that is my issue. Here are my components:

**** Registration Component ****

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

/** UI Framework Components **/
import { Button, Form, Icon, Input } from 'antd'

class FormWrapper extends Component {
render() {
    const { getFieldDecorator } = this.props.form

return (
  <Form layout={'horizontal'}>
    <Form.Item>
      {getFieldDecorator('userName', {
        rules: [{ required: true, message: 'Please input your username!' }]
      })(<Input prefix={<Icon type="user" style={{ color: 'rgba(0,0,0,.25)' }} />} placeholder="Username" />)}
    </Form.Item>
  </Form>
  )
 }
}

export const RegistrationForm = Form.create()(FormWrapper)
```

**** Imported Component ****

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

/** Components **/
import { RegistrationForm } from 'Components/RegistrationForm'

/** UI Framework Components **/
import { Card, Tabs } from 'antd'

/** Styled Components **/
const Wrapper = styled(Card)`
  ${center()};
  width: 500px;
`

const TabPane = Tabs.TabPane 

export class LoginRegisterContainer extends Component {
  state = {
    activeTab: '1'
  }

render() {
   const { activeTab } = this.state

return (
  <Wrapper>
    <Tabs defaultActiveKey={activeTab}>
      <TabPane tab="Register" key="1">
        <RegistrationForm />
      </TabPane>
      <TabPane tab="Log In" key="2">
        <LogIn />
      </TabPane>
    </Tabs>
  </Wrapper>
   )
  }
}
```

I am able to import all components from the library without an issue but when trying to use the form, is when this arises.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough reputation to just comment, but I think the problem is simply that the `<Wrapper />` component doesn't exist. Is this the result you are going for?

[image: Edit antd reproduction template]

Comment: Sorry, the Wrapper does exists. It is a styled component. I realized I forgot to paste that into the code example.

Comment: If I remove the Form.Item and let’s say put a <p> tag, it renders perfectly fine.

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't help. `styled()` is also undefined here and looks like there are some syntax problems. I think your issue exists outside of the code provided here.

Answer (score 0):

First I executed your code, checked for errors, returned the existing components really, maybe you didn't post it, and then I adjusted it, and it was ready to run.

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react'

    /** Components **/
    import { RegistrationForm } from './components/RegistrationForm'

    /** UI Framework Components **/
    import { Tabs } from 'antd'

    const TabPane = Tabs.TabPane

    export default class LoginRegisterContainer extends Component {
      state = {
        activeTab: '1',
      }

      render () {
        const {activeTab} = this.state

        return (
          <div>
            <Tabs defaultActiveKey={activeTab}>
              <TabPane tab="Register" key="1">
                <RegistrationForm/>
              </TabPane>
              <TabPane tab="Log In" key="2">
                {/*<LogIn/>*/}
              </TabPane>
            </Tabs>
          </div>
        )
      }
    }
```

Comment: From Review:  Hi, please don't answer just with source code. Try to provide a nice description about how your solution works. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Thanks